# How to fix Admin SDK custom CMS element not rendered

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

The custom CMS element registered via Admin SDK not rendered

I saw the console error happend in the location-renderer component, which tried to read data from object `elementData`

Environment:

- Shopware: 6.5.7.1
- @shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk: 3.0.16

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there other extensions in the system which touch CMS?

Comment: We've been able to replicate this error when certain other CMS plugins or apps are used. I started a bounty for you :-)

Comment: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-31856
I created the related issue a longtime ago a no one take care of it 
Also in the app-development channel 
https://shopwarecommunity.slack.com/archives/C025YFFMP6W/p1700495234632789